# c# Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0

I am getting this error. When i call the c# WebService using `HttpWebRequest`.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.
```

from wsdl i found the soap action and i added in the request, still it is showing the error

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:33333/AccountService.asmx");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://ttt/test.aspx"
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try "supply[ing] a valid soap action"?

Comment: We need to see more code. How are you calling the service? What method are you calling and what parameters are you passing in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action is specified by the url you post the soap envelope to. Chances are the url either has a typo or you are trying to execute an action that the SOAP service doesn't understand. Check the WSDL for the service and make sure you are calling the proper action.

Answer (score 2):

```
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://ttt/test.aspx/methodname")
```

Method name should be specified after `'test.aspx/'` in above URL.